# How to prove if $x \in W_1$ and $y \in W_1$ then $x + y \in W_1$ when we don't know if $W_1$ is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

As always, I know this website likes to know the motivation, and the motivation is to prove a larger proof. I'm trying to prove that $W_1$ is a subspace.

Part of doing that is to prove that if $x \in W_1$ and $y \in W_1$ then $x + y \in W_1$. I had defined $W_1$ as $W_1 = (V \setminus W_2) \cup \{ 0\}$ where $V$ is a vector space and $W_2$ is a subSPACE. Consequently, $x$ and $y$ are vectors.

I split it into several cases. The case where either vectors is zero, that is $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ is easy to prove. The part I am stuck on is if $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$. I am attempting a proof by contradiction.

I have so far that: Suppose $x \in W_1$ and $y \in W_1$ and $x + y \notin W_1$. Observe $x + y \in V$ since $W_1$ is a subSET of $V$ (needs to be proven). Thus $x + y \in V$ and $x + y \notin W_1$. Thus $x + y \in V \setminus W_1$ by definition of set difference. Now I am stuck.

I know from here I want to show that $x + y \in W_2$ but then that means $x \in W_2$ and $y \in W_2$ which is a contradiction.

A tip in any direction is appreciated. Maybe proof by contradiction was not the best method.

Comment: Trying to prove that something false is true is even worse than not using the best method of proof!

Answer (score 3):

This statement is false.  Suppose $W_2$ is the $x$-axis in the plane and take $x = (1, 1)$ and $y = (1, -1)$.  Then their sum is $(2, 0)$ which is in $W_2$.